# Trying to set up facebook pixel to fire a lead tag after button clicks with JavaScript, what am i doing wrong : (?

Tags: javascript, facebook, triggers, pixel

i'm trying to get my facebook Pixel to fire a lead tag whenever a button on my page is clicked, the button id is set to "submit" however facebook
isn't firing the lead tag properly and i'm really confused as to what is going wrong with my code. I've been trying to figure this out for a few days now.

It's also worth mentioning this is on a wordpress website with a header editor plug in.

```
<button id="#submit">submit</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
var button = document.getElementById('submit');
button.addEventListener(
'click', 
function() { 
fbq('track', 'seanlead', {
});          
},
false
);
</script>
```

Comment: Your button id is `submit`, but your getElementById is looking for `Submit` with a capital S.

Comment: It's still not working : ((( it just refuses to fire, i made the correction you suggested though. the webpage i'm working on is www.lemaladental.com/contact-us the submit button for the contact form

Comment: Remove the `<script>` tag from the first line

Comment: @Aaaron I updated the script in the post, take a look now : )

Comment: Remove # from the button id.